# Pandas function within function ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting create a function to help me create a GeoJSON file. I'm attempting to have a colours property depending on a users gender and activity status. The function that I have created so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def create_geojson(df): 

    def colour_func():
        if (df["Status"] == "Inactive"):                            #line 167
            return "#808080"
        elif (df["Status"] == "Active" and df["Gender"] == "Male"):
            return "#0000FF"
        else:
            return "#FF99FF"

    z = len(df)
    output = "C:\\Users\\Lukasz Obara\\Desktop\\Members.txt"
    f = open(output, "w")
    f.write('var Members = {\n\t' +
            '"type": "FeatureCollection",\n\t' +
            '"features": [')

    for x in range(0, z-1): 
        if (isinstance(df["Addr-Formatted"][x], str)):

            f.write('{\n\t\t"type": "Feature",\n\t\t' +
                '"geometry": {\n\t\t\t' +
                    '"type": "Point",\n\t\t\t' + 
                    '"coordinates": [%f, %f] \n\t\t' % (df["Lng"][x], 
                                                        df["Lat"][x]) +
                    '}, \n\t\t' +
                '"properties": {\n\t\t\t' +
                    '"Name": "%s, %s",\n\t\t\t' % (df['Member Name-First'][x],  
                                                   df['Member Name-Last'][x]) + 
                    '"Colour": "%s" \n\t\t' % colour_func() +
                "}\n\t" +                                        #line 205
            "}, ")

    f.close()
    os.rename(output, "C:\\Users\\Lukasz Obara\\Desktop\\Members.geojson")
```

I figured that `colour_func()` should be empty since it's simply using `df` from `create_geojson` to return the appropriate colour (grey, blue, pink), but I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz Obara\desktop\Test.py", line 205, in create_geojson
    "}\n\t"+
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz Obara\desktop\Test.py", line 167, in colour_func
    if (df["Status"] == "Inactive"):
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz Obara\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 887, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` to combine the two boolean Series not `and`. You also need to group the comparisons in `()`.

So, change:

```
elif (df["Status"] == "Active" and df["Gender"] == "Male"):
```

into:

```
elif ((df["Status"] == "Active) & (df["Gender"] == "Male")):
```

**EDIT**

The traceback helps. You need to specify the index:

```
def colour_func(ind):
    if df.loc[ind, "Status"] == "Inactive":
        return "#808080"
    elif df.loc[ind, "Status"] == "Active" and df.loc[ind, "Gender"] == "Male":
        return "#0000FF"
    else:
        return "#FF99FF"
```

And later call your function with the index `z`:

```
'"Colour": "%s" \n\t\t' % colour_func(z) +
```

Comment: I attempted the changes and the `ValueError` persists.

Comment: Please show the full traceback including the line number. Also identify this line in your code. Otherwise, there is no way to find out where exactly this error happens.

Comment: I've included the full error. I've tested the function without the nested `colour_func()` and I do not generate any error.